# LINQ Type expected

Tags: c#, xml, linq

have the following linq code, trying to parse an xml file to a datatable but i get strange values in the resultant datatable all cell values show as

```
System.Xml.Ling.XContainer+<GetElements>d_11
```

Here is my LINQ

```
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\m.xml");
            var q = from address in doc1.Root.Elements("Address")
                    let name = address.Elements("Name")
                    let street = address.Elements("Street")
                    let city = address.Elements("city")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = name,
                        Street = street,
                        City = city
                    };

            var xdt = new DataTable();

            xdt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            xdt.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(string));
            xdt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));

            foreach (var address in q)
            {
                xdt.Rows.Add(address.Name, address.Street, address.City);
            }

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = xdt.DefaultView;
```

here is my xml:

```
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

and here is the result i get!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to regrieve the inner text of XElements. So you are selecting the whole element with attributes etc. Use this part of code:

```
var q = from address in doc1.Root.Elements("Address")
let name = address.Element("Name")
let street = address.Element("Street")
let city = address.Element("city")
select new
{
    Name = name.Value,
    Street = street.Value,
    City = city.Value
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`address.Elements("Name")` is a *collection* of all of the elements of type "Name".  It so happens that in  your case it's a collection of size one, but it's still a collection.  You want to get the first item out of that collection (since you know it will be the only one) and then get the text value of that element.  If you use `Element` instead of `Elements` you'll get the first item that matches, rather than a collection of items.

Now that you have your single element, you also need to get the value of that element, rather than the element itself (which also contains lots of other information in the general case, even though there really isn't anything else interesting about it in this particular case.

```
var q = from address in doc1.Root.Elements("Address")
        select new
        {
            Name = address.Element("Name").Value,
            Street = address.Element("Street").Value,
            City = address.Element("City").Value
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this work for you?

```
        var q = from address in doc1.Root.Elements("Address")
                let name = (string)(address.Element("Name"))
                let street = (string)(address.Element("Street"))
                let city = (string)(address.Element("city")) 
                //...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Elements` which returns n elements wrapped in a helper class.

You probably mean to call `Element` which returns the first element as an `XElement` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var q = from address in doc1.Root.Elements("Address")
        let name = address.Element("Name").Value
        let street = address.Element("Street").Value
        let city = address.Element("City").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `address.Elements("Name")` to `address.Elements("Name").FirstOrDefault()` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The Elements method returns an IEnumerable. Therefore, your let variables point ato a sequence of elements, not a single element. You should take the single element returned, which will be an XElement, and then take its Value property to get the concatenated text of its contents. (As per documentation)

Instead of

```
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = name,
                        Street = street,
                        City = city
                    }
```

You should write:

```
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = name.Single().Value,
                        Street = street.Single().Value,
                        City = city.Single().Value
                    }
```

Either there, or directly in the let expressions. You may also find a helper method useful:

```
    public static string StringValueOfElementNamed(XElement node, string elementName) {
        return node.Elements(elementName).Single().Value;
    }
```

Turn this helper method into an extension method if you wish to use member access syntax.

**Edit:** After reading concurrent answers, the better method to use would be:

```
    public static string StringValueOfElementNamed(XElement node, string elementName) {
        return node.Element(elementName).Value;
    }
```

Element returns the first found element. Beware the null pointer returned when there is no element found.